# How to verify Websocket connection using script?

Tags: ruby, bash, websocket

I want to automate and monitor my websocket connection whether it is able to send successful response for the connection request. I know different plugins already available but I am looking for a script whether in bash or ruby so that it can test my websocket connection and successful message .
Any help will be very much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: echo.websocket.org" -H "Origin: http://www.websocket.org" http://echo.websocket.org
```

Where `http://www.websocket.org` is host origin, and `echo.websocket.org` is endpoint for websocket.

Those flags say:

- Return headers in the output
- Don’t buffer the response
- Set a header that this connection needs to upgrade from HTTP to something else
- Set a header that this connection needs to upgrade to a WebSocket connection
- Set a header to define the host (required by later WebSocket standards)
- Set a header to define the origin of the request (required by later WebSocket standards)

If your WebSocket is working running the above should return the handshake information, for further information, refer to [this post](http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24889968081/debugging-websockets-with-curl)

Comment: Isn't that only really testing 1/2 the connection? There's the websocket component as well.

Comment: But how does this really tell whether connection is open and sending successful messages, I am little unclear with the solution above.

Comment: If webSocket is available, it will return handshake, which then handled with webSocket browser javaScript library as i understand